# How can I render template in a variable with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, template-engine, vue.js

In mustache.js, [templates can be passed as an argument of `Mustache.render()` as follows](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#usage):

```
var view = {
  title: "Joe",
  calc: function () {
    return 2 + 4;
  }
};

var output = Mustache.render("{{title}} spends {{calc}}", view);
```

I'm looking for a way to use Vue.js in that way, render a template which stored in a variable, then return rendered HTML from [`render` function of jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render), without manipulating DOM.

Can I achieve this with Vue.js? If I can't, Should I use mustache.js to implement this instead of Vue.js? Any advices of better way would be also greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if I'm getting it right, but this is like setting the `template` property in a Vue component or instance? the template propertie get a string that is rendered where the `el` property is set

Comment: Hi Yerko, using `template` property sounds promising. do you have any idea to get rendered HTML without modifying DOM (e.g. getting the rendered HTML as return value of a method)?

Comment: if you get html rendered then you are modifying the DOM. There is no way to render html without adding it to the DOM. you might want to dynamically display your html? in that case you should look at `v-if` directive which will only insert the html to display in the DOM if a certain condition is met.

Comment: You are right, but I don't want to modify DOM myself. I want jQuery DataTables to do it via implementing [this callback function](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) which returns rendered HTML string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could approximate the Mustache behavior with something like this:

```
var view = new Vue({
    data: {
        title: 'Joe'
    },
    methods: {
      calc: function () {
        return 2 + 4;
      }    
    }
})

var output = view.$interpolate('{{title}} spends {{calc()}}');
```

Comment: Great, exactly it's what I was looking for! I've confirmed that your solution works with vue.js 0.11.0.

Comment: Just a little more - do you have any idea to get HTML characters escaped (e.g. `<` => `&lt;`) automatically with this way?

Comment: I mean, I want to get HTML characters escaped automatically for template parameters that `{{ title }}` and `{{ calc }}`.

Comment: is supossed that you can use [raw html](http://vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Raw_HTML) with three curly braces like this `{{{ <br /> }}}` I don't know if that works with the interpolate function

Comment: The html characters should be escaped when you do this. If `title` contains <, it will be converted to &lt;. On the other hand, as @Yerko points out, if you have raw html that you don't want escaped, you can use the triple braces. These will work with $interpolate().

Comment: @Peter Hmm... it doesn't work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/3do2v327/1/ Am I missing something?

Comment: FYI: I asked about it in vue.js gitter, and unfortunately I got an answer which I can't do it  https://gitter.im/vuejs/vue?at=56cf8a3ed7513d907aa541b8 . still looking for a way to do it.

Comment: @Kohei - sorry about that; I guess I was wrong about the escaping. I could have sworn I tested this before commenting but I guess not. In any case, I think Mustache templates would be much better suited to your scenario - rendering a template string for a DataTables column. Vue.js is designed to handle scenarios where it is rendering the DOM and reactively bind it to your data.

Comment: I was thinking of another solution that manually escaping all of properties of `data` object before passing it to vue, but it's looks clumsy so I would go with Mustache this time, as you mentioned. thank you guys anyway!

Comment: @Peter, **view.$interpolate is not a function (((** unfortunately

Comment: Yes, this function existed in vue v1 but was removed in v2. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#vm-interpolate-removed